# Updating library from Angular 9 to Angular 10 produces error Symbol MatButton declared in ....is not exported from @angular/material/button

Tags: angular-material, angular-library, angular10

After updating the Angular lib from angular 9 to angular 10, I am getting the following error while building the library.

```
ERROR: Symbol MatButton declared in ...........................  is not exported from @angular/material/button.
```

I couldn't understand the reason, can somebody please suggest what needs to be done?

Thanks,
Meenakshi

Comment: Please check if this helps - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35611

Comment: @buchipper though it seems related, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Which import statement do you use? Is it `import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after enabling ivy while my imports were correct. For me updating `@angular/material` to `11.2.10` and updating `@angular/compiler-cli` to `11.2.11` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue with another module. My problem was that I imported module through deep path instead of short one.

Error occurs:

```
import { SomeModule } from 'npm-package-name/some.module';
```

No error:

```
import { SomeModule } from 'npm-package-name';
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The exports and directory layout in JS packages really depend on the package.